# Jquery Popeye plugin z-index issue IE7

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, z-index

im struggling with a jquery plugin.

http://dev.herr-schuessler.de/jquery/popeye/

It works in all browsers apart from IE7, where the enlarged image goes behind the other instances.

You can see my dev site here, click on one of the thumbs.  http://designbychief.com/ms

(There may be some other css layout issues that need ironing out, but im just focusing on getting this plugin to work in IE7.)

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, IE and z-index are the bane of my life.

Try adding `position:relative;` to the affected elements; that may solve it.

(And also add `position:relative;` to parents of affected elements)

If that doesn't help (and it seems it doesn't), here's a link that explains how to get around some more IE z-index quirks: http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, I have tried adding to .port-container